# Return and verify the existence of an element using Webstorm IDE expression while running Protractor

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor, webstorm

When performing debugging over the pages I want to make sure that I was able to find an element and play with its values using the expressions.

When I put the ElementFinder and try to take the webelement I need to resolve the promise, it's there any way that I can see webelement properties inside the expression like you can do in belows example ( see second image attached ).

[image]
[image]